# Formula (According to Blender) to create an Enneper Order 3

Tags: modeling

This is what an Enneper looks like in Blender, according to Math Functions - XYZ:

[image: Blender Enneper - Math Function - XYZ]

This is an [Enneper, Order 3](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/enneper/enneper.shtml)

[image: Enneper Order 3]

The XYZ Functions (Enneper Blender) are as follows:

[image: Blender XYZ Function Formulas for Enneper Surface]

Is there a way to modify the default XYZ formula for Enneper, XYZ to create an Enneper Order 3?  Is it better suited to Blender Python?  Or perhaps Sverchok, especially now with Sverchok Extras - with an eye to minimal surfaces (of which Enneper is one)?

Can it be done, and if so how? If not, what would be a better avenue to pursue?

Addendum:

I did come up with this modified for Blender from MathMod.  It's different.  It's no Order 3.  Missing a side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the formula [here](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/enneper/enneper.shtml):

[image]

If `a` stands for `n` (so 3 in our case) and `b` for `2n-1` (so 5), then:

```
x = u*cos(v)-(u**b * cos(b*v) / b)

y = u*sin(v)+(u**b * sin(b*v) / b)

z = 2 * (u**a) * cos(a*v)/a
```

with:

```
0 < u < 1.2
-pi < v < pi
```

And:

```
a = 3
b = 2 * a - 1
```

Which is:

[image]

Then:

[image]

If you want to push u to its limits, set it between:

```
0 < u < sqrt(2)
```

[image]

And you can change the order setting a and b differently (b = 2 * a - 1), for instance:

[image]

If useful, here is the preset file *"enneper_n.py"* that can be stored into the preset directory (on Windows):

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\presets\operator\mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface
```

Its content is:

```
import bpy
op = bpy.context.active_operator

op.x_eq = 'u*cos(v)-(u**b * cos(b*v) / b)'
op.y_eq = 'u*sin(v)+(u**b * sin(b*v) / b)'
op.z_eq = '2 * (u**a) * cos(a*v)/a'
op.range_u_min = 0.0
op.range_u_max = 1.2000000476837158
op.range_u_step = 32
op.wrap_u = False
op.range_v_min = -3.1415927410125732
op.range_v_max = 3.1415927410125732
op.range_v_step = 128
op.wrap_v = False
op.close_v = False
op.n_eq = 1
op.a_eq = '3'
op.b_eq = '2*a-1'
op.c_eq = '0'
op.f_eq = '0'
op.g_eq = '0'
op.h_eq = '0'
op.show_wire = True
op.edit_mode = False
```

Comment: That's a confusing one.... where you transliterated `cos(2n-1)t` as `cos(b*v)`, I would have gone for `cos(b)*v` ... everything looks ok, you must be right ....

Comment: @RobinBetts, don't think so... here no parenthesis for cos https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/enneper/enneper.shtml ... but I could be wrong... but if you try it, you'll see

Comment: @RobinBetts if cos or sin independent of v, so finally a constant value.... can it work? don't think so

Comment: Exactly.. you must be right. Confusing notation, though (theirs, not yours)

Comment: @RobinBetts, have edited the answer with a blend in which i have saved "enneper N" preset. Not sure this preset is included in the file, but you can test it.

Comment: @RobinBetts, Please let me know if the preset is saved in the linked file (if not this is saved in my env only...).

Comment: I have your object, and an Enneper preset, but not yours.. where are the presets stashed, I wonder? And how would you pack them? (minutes pass )... been looking, quickly .. [this](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-blenders-presets-in-python/) is my best clue.. they can't be packed?

Comment: The preset would be saved separate from the Blend file, locally.  They're ordinarily kept in a separate folder.  The good news is they can be readily copied / updated from one blender version to the next.

On my Mac, they're located (version 2.90)

/Users/usernameLibrary/Application Support/Blender/2.90/scripts/presets

In the presets folder is where the "Operator Presets" are kept, each in a folder corresponding to the function used, in this case:  XYZ.

There are "py" files that can be shared.

Comment: P.S. Outstanding!  Learned sometjhing today.  Not only how to do it, that it can be done, but, an example of the use of the a,b,... variables.

Insight into transforming / transposing other comparable formulas.

Comment: Not sure how "2*a-1" provides a different result from the initial formula "2*a-1"?  A rest of the story maybe?

Comment: Didn't get the result as shown at the bottom.  But, I did get an interesting oddity via b = 2 * (2*a-1)

Comment: Asked on Blender Artists first.  Got the answer here first.  Shared it on Blender Artists and got this from Paul:  https://blenderartists.org/t/enneper-order-3-math-function-x-y-z/1252783/31.  Another interesting way to go about it.  Cheers!

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk, thanks for the link. What do you mean by "Not sure how "2*a-1" provides a different result from the initial formula "2*a-1"?"

Comment: I'm able to create the first two from your examples, but not the last one.  You reference, I think, "2*a-1", as an example for that code.  It's the same as the code from up above in the image as well as the text.  

The code from Paul at Blenderartists helps with that by having a helper operation specific to Order.

I've also shared some presets based o Paul's code and some other enneper examples that fit inside the Presets for XYZ.  Both Paul and I have some examples (zipped) as to location (linux, Windows, Mac) and process.

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk, have you tried to lower *U max* for the last one?

Comment: Figured it out. It's not U max that creates the last one.  It's your A helper that's the Order.  Up scaling or down scaling that changes the Order.

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk, yes change A value, say 8, (keep B as it is 2 * a - 1), should be ok but should decrease U max as if not will overlap.

Comment: I misunderstood / misread that last one.

Comment: @fewerjunkjunk have added preset content at the end of the answer.