# Pringle's potato chip - XYZ or Z Function what would that look like?

Tags: modeling, mathematics

Would it be better done as a Z formula or an XYZ formula?

And if so, how?

According to this link:

http://mathandmultimedia.com/2011/04/15/potato-chips-and-mathematics/

That would be, mathematically speaking a

"hyperbolic paraboloid quadratic and doubly ruled surface"

of cartesian equation as explained at the link above.

Not a hyperbolic paraboloid, saddle, as is commonly shown, but, rounded, all around

as shown below:

[image: Pringle's Chip]

Comment: Since you already know the analytic form as a Z function; it should definitely be a Z formula

Comment: The way I read it, it translates to (y**y / b**b) - (x**x / a**a).  Z formula has no a or b variables.  Only x or y.  So, how would I factor in a or b?  Assigning a random integer as a constant for a or b in that formulation isn't working.  And it's entirely possible that I'm off in left field.

Comment: Ok, worked out the proper interpretation (y^2 / 2^2) - (x^2 / 2^2) [ Except without the ^ - the other way] -  but that gives me an un-rounded hyperbolic paraboloid.  Close.  But no cigar.

Comment: I've got this formula mod (XYZ - Enneper) from a previous question here.  It looks close, but, it's not a Z formula:  https://imgur.com/a/XZh422I

Comment: StackExchange (Enneper) - Here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194257/formula-according-to-blender-to-create-an-enneper-order-3

Comment: a and b are constants.  You pick those values to influence the shape of your curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offered the comment that you should use a Z formula but I neglected that a Z formula would give you a square potato chip.

[image: surface y2/4-x2/9]

That's a Z function that uses 2 as a and 3 as b.

To get a round potato chip you would use an XYZ surface:

[image: the same as an XYZ function]

Here is what it looks like

[image: the potato chip]

Explanation:

To get the round shape I used *polar* coordinates.  I used u to represent the polar radius and v to represent the polar angle, in radians.  The two helper functions g and h convert the polar coordinates for x and y.  The values in the helper functions a and b control how 'bendy' the chip is along the respective axis.

Comment: It's close Marty, but, if you look at the image, you've got it right on the sides, but it looks more like a pancake folded at the edges than the Pringles chip in the example image.  As I look at it, it goes up on the left / right.  It needs to come down on the front and back.

Comment: It's a matter of tuning the settings, particularly a and b.  I just picked two numbers at random.  If I wanted to do a chip I'd add a subsurf after a solidify also

Comment: I was just going to add, playing with a and b brought me closer to the mark:  https://imgur.com/a/S9DQ2zj

Comment: Noticed one small, common problem. as shown: https://imgur.com/a/S9DQ2zj

I tried merge by distance, played around with the subd settings and added a displace.  Still visible.

I think it would go away with a wireframe though.

Comment: Make sure that U wrap is off, that V wrap is on, and that Close V is off.  If you don't wrap V then floating point math bites you.  You'll also have to merge by distance

Comment: Yeah, figuring it all out.  That was next on my list.

Comment: Updated to reflect changes: https://imgur.com/a/S9DQ2zj